# Dropping a DDL Trigger gives error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created a simple trigger using the below code

```
Create Trigger preventDrop on Database for Drop_Table   
AS
    Print 'You cannot Drop a Table'
    RollBack;
Go
```

And It works Ok. It does not let me drop a Table. But Now When I drop this trigger using

```
drop Trigger preventDrop
```

It does not let me drop the trigger and gives the following error

```
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 10
Cannot drop the trigger 'preventDrop', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dropping DDL Triggers requires the syntax:

```
DROP TRIGGER preventDrop ON DATABASE;
```

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173497.aspx)

Comment: One more thing @LDMJoe Is this the correct syntax of creating a trigger? Because It gives red line under it in MS Sql Server

Comment: @BilalRafique Try refreshing the window

Comment: @WilliamBurnham Did it but still underlined red

Comment: Your Management Studio for an older version of SQL Server than your target maybe?  I think the parsing is done client side, so if your SSMS was old and didn't know about the syntax it may complain, but when executed against a more modern version of server may go ahead and work just fine?  Pure speculation.